# Ошибка при подключении к БД

Tags: php

Что может значить такая ошибка?

[Ошибка](http://holm.ru/cgi_error.html/33/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто место на сервере заканчивается. Вообщем проблема на стороне хостера, пиши в тех.поддержку, на форум и т.д.